# Read csv file with column as literal list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, csv

I have a csv file with a few columns. One of the columns contains rows with literal python-formatted lists in them and I would like to read them into a list of lists.

**CSV file**

```
val1 ['foo', 'bar']
val2 ['baz']
val3 ['a','b','c']
```

What I've tried so far is;

```
with open('data.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_read = csv.reader(csv_file)
    values, value_lists = zip(*csv_read)
    value_lists = ast.literal_eval(value_lists)

for val, value_lists in zip(values, value_lists):
    for single_list in value_lists:
        print(f'{val}: {single_list}')
```

`ast.literal_eval()` gives a `ValueError('malformed node or string: ' + repr(node))` error.

I'd like value_lists to contain `[['foo', 'bar'],['baz'],['a','b','c']]`.

**Answer**

Using `value_lists = map(ast.literal_eval, value_lists)` instead worked exactly how I wanted. Thanks @PhilipTzou

Comment: `value_lists = map(ast.literal_eval, value_lists)`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use:

```
file = open('csv_parse.txt'); content = file.readlines(); file.close()
result = []
[result.append(eval(x.split(" ", 1)[1])) for x in content]
print(result)
```

---

Output:

```
[['foo', 'bar'], ['baz'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]
```